# Set encryption per parameter

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, encryption

i'm new to T-SQL and i got the following question:

Is it possible to set the encryption per parameter? Something like this: (pseudo code)

```
create or alter procedure [db].[my_new_proc]
   @Parameter1 int
   @Parameter2 int
   @ParEncryptYN bit

if @ParEncryptYN = 1
  AS
else
  WITH ENCRYPTION AS
end
begin
...
end
```

I know that i can't use if there, thats why i'm asking.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible, but perhaps there is a solution depending upon what you're actually try to do.  Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: For example: i have my application which calls the storedprocedure.In case of the customer the storedporcedure should be executed encrypted, but if i want for example to debug then i would like to tell the procedure to be executed normally.

Comment: In your development environment, create the SPs without encryption.  In your production environment, create the SPs with encryption.  It's not controllable via a flag - either the SP is encrypted, or it is not

Comment: Okay, thats what i wanted to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following OP's explanation that they are looking for a way to protect the T-SQL in their SPs when deployed in client environments, the problem can be clarified.

There is no way to control whether a SP is encrypted using a parameter to the SP.  This is because the SP is encrypted when it is *created* not when it is *executed*.

A simple approach that allows SPs to be altered in development but protected in production is to simply create the SPs without encryption in development, and with encrytpion in production.

For example, in your development environment:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [db].[my_new_proc]
   @Parameter1 int
   @Parameter2 int
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

In your production environment:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [db].[my_new_proc]
   @Parameter1 int
   @Parameter2 int
  WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Comment: [quote] There is no way to control whether a SP is encrypted using a parameter to the SP. This is because the SP is encrypted when it is created not when it is executed. [/quote]


That's what i wanted to know and thank you for the example, too.